# Выводить в file.txt скорость работы SSD на VDS по времени

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu 16.04.
Следующей командой вывожу в консоль "скорость работы SSD":

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile bs=64k count=16k conv=fdatasync
```

Получаю вот это:

```
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 2.89957 s, 370 MB/s
```

Теперь нужно каждые двадцать минуть повторять эту команду, но результат нужно записывать в файл. Как это сделать?

Comment: ставить на ``cron`` и использовать ``>>`` results.txt

Comment: @1stSentinel31YearPerlHist ответы - в ответы. Только чуть более развёрнуто, со строкой в crontab

Comment: Нет, пока без кронтаба пусть.

Comment: https://habr.com/post/154235/

Answer (score 1):

```
watch -n 1200 "dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile bs=64k count=16k conv=fdatasync >> /home/vasya/file.txt"
```

---

Каждые 1200 секунд будет выполняться команда `dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile bs=64k count=16k conv=fdatasync` а результат будет записываться в файл `file.txt`, который лежит в домашней папке вашего пользователя.

---

See [watch(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) for more information;

See [crontab(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) for more information.

[Наглядный пример](http://blog.sedicomm.com/2017/07/24/kak-dobavit-zadanie-v-planirovshhik-cron-v-linux-unix/), как пользоваться crontab'ом.

Comment: спасибо. А можно дописать, чтобы еще и время текущее добавлялось к началу каждой строки?

Comment: Можно, но это уже другой вопрос. Задайте соответсвующий вопрос.

Comment: Создал новый вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/914656/Выводить-в-file-txt-скорость-работы-ssd-на-vds-по-времени-каждые-20-минут

Comment: Хм) конечно ssd не вечен, как и сам вопрос не подразумевает другого решения задачи. Но вы уверены что вам нужно иметь замер скорости ssd? при этом активно (каждые 1200с) исчерпывать его (хоть немного, но всеже).